# PropertyChangedEventManager and Moq'd Interfaces

Tags: c#, moq, inotifypropertychanged

When Mocking (using Moq) an interface/object that supports INotifyPropertyChanged, using PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler doesn't property connect up to the event as raised by Raise. A direct += connection works correctly however:

```
bool _EventMangerCalled = false;
bool _DirectCalled = false;

private void EventManagerHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _EventMangerCalled = true;
}

private void DirectHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _DirectCalled = true;
}

[TestMethod]
public void PropertyChangedEventManager_AddHandler_OnMoq()
{
    var m = new Mock<INotifyPropertyChanged>();
    m.Object.PropertyChanged += DirectHandler;
    PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(m.Object, EventManagerHandler, "Foo");

    m.Raise(x=>x.PropertyChanged += null, this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Foo"));
    // Success
    Assert.IsTrue(_DirectCalled, "directCalled is not true");
    // Failure
    Assert.IsTrue(_EventMangerCalled, "eventManagerCalled is not true"); 
}
```

I've also tried string.Empty instead of "Foo" in the AddHandler (the way it happens in my actual code). Is there a different way to Raise the event which would work, or any ideas of another way around this? I want to be able to test the event handling of objects which require weak subscriptions.

Comment: Can you specify what business rule are you trying to test here? I believe SUT is your `PropertyChangedEventManager` class. What is purpose of this class?

Comment: PropertyChangedEventManager is in System.ComponentModel. This adds weak event listening to facilitate cleanup of objects that subscribe to events of other objects with a longer (or different) lifespan.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, think about your first assertion:

```
var mock = new Mock<INotifyPropertyChanged>();
mock.Object.PropertyChanged += DirectHandler;
mock.Raise(x=>x.PropertyChanged += null, this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Foo"));
Assert.IsTrue(_DirectCalled, "directCalled is not true");
```

You verify that when you raise event on mock object, event handler (which is attached to event of mocked object) will be called. In other words, *you are testing implementation of Moq library*. Don't worry, it's already tested.

Next, to raise event you don't need to pass reference to class where your tests are defined (`this`) - simply pass EventArgs which should be passed to handlers:

```
.Raise(m => m.PropertyChanged += null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Foo"))
```

It's hard to tell what behavior your `PropertyChangedEventManager` should have, but I assume that it should run given handler if source object raised `NotifyPropertyChanged` event for given property. Sounds good. It's easy to test handler invocations with clojures - use lambda delegate which captures local variable (flag) and changes it when lambda was called:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldInvokeHandlerWhenSpecifiedPropertyChanged()
{
    var sourceMock = new Mock<INotifyPropertyChanged>();
    var sut = new PropertyChangedEventManager();
    bool handlerInvoked = false;
    sut.AddHandler(sourceMock.Object, (s, e) => handlerInvoked = true, "Foo");

    sourceMock.Raise(m => m.PropertyChanged += null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Foo"));

    Assert.IsTrue(handlerInvoked);
}
```

Simplest implementation which makes this test pass will be

```
public class PropertyChangedEventManager
{
    public void AddHandler(
        INotifyPropertyChanged source,
        EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> handler,
        string propertyName)
    {
        source.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => {
            if (e.PropertyName == propertyName)
                handler(s, e);
        };
    }
}
```

Next you should check that handler was not called if source raised event for other property. Change two lines:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldNotInvokeHandlerWhenOtherPropertyChanged()
{
    var sourceMock = new Mock<INotifyPropertyChanged>();
    var sut = new PropertyChangedEventManager();
    bool handlerInvoked = false;
    sut.AddHandler(sourceMock.Object, (s, e) => handlerInvoked = true, "Foo");

    sourceMock.Raise(m => m.PropertyChanged += null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Bar"));

    Assert.IsFalse(handlerInvoked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... For the direct case, the "sender" is never checked. But the PropertyChangedManager uses it as a key for subscriptions. My:

```
m.Raise(x=>x.PropertyChanged += null, this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Foo"));
```

Should have been:

```
m.Raise(x=>x.PropertyChanged += null, m.Object, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Foo"));
```